# Stop google from crawling specific link on each page

Tags: robots.txt, google-custom-search

I made a sort of silly error in judgement when I first started developing my site using LESS CSS. With LESS, you can see real-time updates if you include #!watch at the end of the url. So, being a proper lazy developer, I made a button on my dev page that only I knew about that would append the current URL with #!watch.

However, Google is treating that href as a legitimate link, and now all my pages are being indexed twice - once for the "normal" page, and once with the #!watch appended to the URL.

My question is how can I remove the !#watch from the Google indexing? Would a robot.txt line work to do that? It wouldn't really be so much of a problem, but I'm also using the Google Custom Search internally, so when a user searches within my site, I'm serving too many results for the same content.

Comment: lol, that's funny.... but if you want to try: http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm going to do is set up a sitemap.xml doc with each of those offending links set to expire. I wrote a short python script to iterate over each line (some 18,000 links) and spit out the formatted xml. It looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://oq.totaleclips.com/mpa/The_Rise_of_the_Guardians_The_Video_Game_(Game)#!watch</loc>      
        <expires>2012-10-08</expires>
    </url>
   ....... (many more url entries)
</urlset>
```

Note the `<expires>`tag, which is read by Google, if not other search engines, as a cut-off date for the indexing. They'll still show up for 30-60 days, apparently, and then will stopped being returned as search results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a canonical link meta tag. It tells search engines what the real page path is and as such should only trigger indexing once despite any hash tags or query strings appended to the path.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Looks like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/realPagePath/" />
```

Comment: I've already got rel="canonical" on each page. The "bad" links are still around after 30-45 days